# open ecw file in mapwindow

Tags: ecw, mapwindow, geodatabase-xml

I'm very new to mapping.

I have a bunch of ecw files and also xml files with their mapping information.

I'm trying to load them in mapwindow but am having no success.

Can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].